# Ubuntu 12.04 and openssh-server

Tags: ssh

I have a problem installing openssh server and client on Ubuntu 12.04 desktop.

I want to make a home server, but I am a Windows user and I need a graphic interface. First of all, I used the command `sudo apt-get update` and I updated all. When I typed: `sudo apt-get openssh-server` I got this:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 openssh-server : Depends: openssh-client (= 1:5.9p1-5ubuntu1) but 1:5.9p1-5ubuntu1.1 is to be installed
                  Recommends: ssh-import-id but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

I am a newb in Linux, and I Googled the error or problem but no answer :/

Can anybody help?

Comment: the correct command to use when installing software is `sudo apt-get install <package-name>`. In your case, make sure your computer is fully up to date: `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade` then install openssh `sudo apt-get install openssh-server`

Comment: @amc I'm pretty sure he **did** use the correct command judging from the output; it's just a typo in his question.

Answer (score 10):

I have had the same problem. I tried this and it works for me.

```
sudo apt-get install openssh-client=1:5.9p1-5ubuntu1
sudo apt-get install openssh-server
```

Comment: This helped me on ubuntu 14.04 as well. The trying to install openssh-client with the version reported in the error downgraded it and thereafter server got installed easily.

Answer (score 2):

Posting because I've spent waaaay too many hours trying to figure this out:

MadMike's answer almost got me there...what I had to do was:

```
    sudo apt-add-repository "deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu precise main restricted"
    sudo apt-get update
    sudo apt-get install openssh-client=1:5.9p1-5ubuntu1
    sudo apt-get install openssh-server
```

and you're done!

Answer (score 1):

On fresh install of Ubuntu 12.04.5 Desktop i386,
I just had the same problem.

```
sudo apt-get install e2fslibs=1.42-1ubuntu2
sudo apt-get install openssh-client=1:5.9p1-5ubuntu1
sudo apt-get install openssh-server=1:5.9p1-5ubuntu1
```

This solved it for me.

Answer (score 0):

---

@Terminal

**check architecture**
`user@precise_12_04:~$ lscpu`
`Architecture:          i686`
`CPU op-mode(s):        32-bit, 64-bit`
`Byte Order:            Little Endian`

---

@Web Browser (p.s. Firefox)

**browse to** https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/openssh/1:5.9p1-5ubuntu1

**choose "Builds"** mine is "i386"

**choose "Binary packages"**  (one at a time)
openssh-client 1:5.9p1-5ubuntu1 (for dependencies)
openssh-server 1:5.9p1-5ubuntu1

**copy "Downloadable files"**
http://launchpadlibrarian.net/99631526/openssh-client_5.9p1-5ubuntu1_i386.deb
http://launchpadlibrarian.net/99631527/openssh-server_5.9p1-5ubuntu1_i386.deb

---

@Terminal

**download client & server**
`user@precise_12_04:~$ wget http://launchpadlibrarian.net/99631526/openssh-client_5.9p1-5ubuntu1_i386.deb`
`user@precise_12_04:~$ wget http://launchpadlibrarian.net/99631527/openssh-server_5.9p1-5ubuntu1_i386.deb`

**install locally**
`user@precise_12_04:~$ sudo dpkg -i openssh-client_5.9p1-5ubuntu1_i386.deb`
`user@precise_12_04:~$ sudo dpkg -i openssh-server_5.9p1-5ubuntu1_i386.deb`

**check service is running**
`user@precise_12_04:~$ service ssh status`

**check open port**
`user@precise_12_04:~$ netstat -tlnp | grep 22`

---

Done